# How to add custom field to Checkouts Total Sort Order?

Tags: checkout, totals, sort

I need to add my custom item to Checkout Total Sort Order in configuration page. I created custom price, which shown in checkout according to this manual https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/
Difference only in that my custom field is calculated via math formula. So now, having new field in checkout, I need to add this field to Checkout Total Sort Order. Question is that how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your extension system.xml

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales>
            <groups>
                <totals_sort>
                    <fields>
                        <yourfield translate="label">
                            <label>Your Field Label</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </yourfield>
                    </fields>
                </totals_sort>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

instend of  you need to use your code. ex "discount","grand_total"

Look in to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Collector

```
protected function _initRetrievers()
    {
        $sorts = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SALES_TOTALS_SORT, $this->_store);
        foreach ($sorts as $code => $sortOrder) {
            if (isset($this->_models[$code])) {
                // Reserve enough space for collisions
                $retrieverId = 100 * (int) $sortOrder;
                // Check if there is a retriever with such id and find next available position if needed
                while (isset($this->_retrievers[$retrieverId])) {
                    $retrieverId++;
                }
                $this->_retrievers[$retrieverId] = $this->_models[$code];
            }
        }
        ksort($this->_retrievers);
        $notSorted = array_diff(array_keys($this->_models), array_keys($sorts));
        foreach ($notSorted as $code) {
            $this->_retrievers[] = $this->_models[$code];
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But I have another question: if I have 1 field with order "10" and my field with order "5", should I expect that my field must be higher that standard field? Or to realize it must be additional code.

Comment: Updated answer please check it